# ERROR <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8"> DJANGO

Tags: django

Me sale error <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8"> al pasar la ip el problema es que parece ser que pide html y no sé como poder pasarle

```
class fichador_view_entrada(CreateViewEntrada):
model = fichador
fields = ['Codigo']
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.tipo = "Entrada"
    form.instance.ip = getIPAddresses(self)
    return super(fichador_view_entrada, self).form_valid(form)

def getIPAddresses(self):
  import socket
  hostname = socket.gethostname()
  ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
  return HttpResponse(ip_add)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comento si quieres regresar un template con HttpResponse() es de la siguiente manera:

```
import socket

def getIPAddresses(self):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    html = "<html><body>IP: %s.</body></html>" % ip_add
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Ahora si vas a regresar un template la mejor opción es usar render() al cual le indicas el nombre del archivo html, le pasas un contexto y lo reemplaza en el archivo, render() ya se encarga de buscar el template, abrirlo, pasarle el contexto y regresarte una respuesta Http, seria de esta manera:

```
import socket

def getIPAddresses(request):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    return render(request, 'mi_template.html',
                  {'ip': ip_add})
```

Y dentro de miapp/templates/mi_template.html (usando la configuración de TEMPLATES como se muestra aqui: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-django-templates)

```
<html>
<body>
IP: {{ ip }}
</body>
</html>
```

Espero esto te sea de ayuda, saludos.